# How to color label on radio-button on react-materialize

Tags: reactjs, materialize

How do I color the label of a radio button created using **react-materialize** Input component?

Sample code of the radioButtons are something like this?

```
<div className="col s2 offset-s3">
    <Input className="with-gap" label="List" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="group"/>
</div>
<div className="col s2">
    <Input className="with-gap" label="User" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="user"/>
</div>
<div className="col s2">
    <Input className="with-gap" label="data" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="data"/>
</div>
```

I tried adding the style property, but that is actually getting added to input element in html. Can someone help me here?

Thanks,
Sreeraj

Answer (score 1):

In `react-materialize` there is no option to set `class` for `input > radio > lable`.

So i have fork the repo and updated https://github.com/piyushdhamecha/react-materialize, added `labelClassName` to `Input` component

```
npm install --save https://github.com/piyushdhamecha/react-materialize
```

You can use like:

```
<Input labelClassName="radioLabel" className="with-gap" label="List" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="group"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a camel case the `classname` to the `className` 
this reference for styling in reactjs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

and this for reactmateralize reference 
https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms

```
<div className="col s2 offset-s3">
    <Input className="with-gap" label="List" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="group"/>
</div>
<div classname="col s2">
    <Input className="with-gap" label="User" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="user"/>
</div>
<div classname="col s2">
    <Input className="with-gap" label="data" name="homePageSearchRadio" type="radio" value="data"/>
</div>
```